# Passing template to swimlane/ngx-datatable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-template, angular2-ngcontent

I am using swimlane/ngx-datatable component and I developed a wrapper for ngx-datatable.

Wrapper:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ngx-datatable [rows]="rows">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

Use:

```html
<app-wrapper>
  <ngx-datatable-column name="Name">
   
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
    
     <span>{{ value }}</span>
  
    </ng-template>
  
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</app-wrapper>
```

This does not work, custom html that I wrote inside app-wrapper is not passed to the component. How would someone go through this if the component already uses ng-template?

Comment: you can use TemplateRef

Comment: Tried that, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to ngx-datatable. Angular doesn't currently support content projection with ng-content more that 2 levels of components deep. No, using ng-content inside ngx-datatable inside app-wrapper will not work.